# Philosophical take on Schrodinger's cat paradox

Tags: quantum-mechanics, schroedinger-equation, thought-experiment

I'm a mathematics undergrad currently doing a module on quantum mechanics. I am interested to delve into the more philosophical aspect of the paradox.

Could anyone please give me some introductory ideas to introduce me the philosophical issues that arise?

Comment: After reading such articles as the one on Wikipedia (here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6dinger's_cat), perhaps you could make your question a bit more precise? I ask for precision because "philosophical issues" could mean a broad spectrum of things some of which might be of interest to physicists, and others, well, are more appropriate for a philosophy forum (if even that). Here is also something you might be interested in: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EPR_paradox.

Comment: Have a read through article 1 on [Rick Bradford's site](http://rickbradford.co.uk/ChoiceCuts.html). This seems to me the most sensible description of the experiment that I've seen. You might want to read the second article (on decoherence) since this is related.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about philosophy.

Comment: Have you heard of quantum suicide. I recently read about it and I was like "whaaa"